# Rexx - Square brackets usage

Tags: windows, zos, rexx

I am quite new to Rexx, really basic stuff here, I want to get the last element of an array quickly.

Open Object Rexx 4.2.0 for Windows:

```
test.0=2
test.1="foo"
test.2="bar"
say test.[test.0]
```

==> Output as wanted:

```
bar
```

---

My easy guess is that the Open Object Rexx interpreter is at work. Square brackets can't be used with Rexx on z/OS.

1st stuff that came to my mind (didn't RTFM) :

```
say test.test.0
say test.(test.0)
```

==> Output not good:

```
TEST.TEST.0
    5 *-* say test.(test.0)
Error 16 running Test.REX line 5:  Label not found
Error 16.1:  Label "SYNTAX" not found
```

Is there other usages of square brackets ?
Why coming from C/Java/Python I am going for test.test.0 or test.(test.0) like a dummy ?

Can't find more information about square brackets usage in Rexx than this: [#Reginald's tail expression](http://nokix.sourceforge.net/help/learn_rexx/array.htm)

So under z/OS for now I am stuck with:

```
temp=test.0
say test.temp
```

Comment: I happen to do some Rexx under Windows & z/OS. Yes, it's not natural.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have found the answer to your question already.

The only way under mainframe REXX (z/OS, z/VSE, z/VM) is as you coded above:

> ```
> temp=test.0
> say test.temp
> ```

The best documentation for understanding what the REXX interpreter is doing can be found in the z/OS TSO/E REXX Reference under [Compound Symbols](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v2r1/topic/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ikja300/compsym.htm) (V2.1 link). It describes why test.test.0 won't work, because of how the interpreter handles the line; in this case, it is looking for a stem test.test.0.

Note that you could code

```
test.test.0 = 0
```

and you would have a valid stem test.test.0 (albeit probably useless in most cases).

The next topic in the link discusses stem variables, which also has lots of useful information.

I highly recommend reading both the [z/OS TSO/E REXX Reference](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v2r1/topic/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ikja300/toc.htm) and the [z/OS TSO/E REXX User's Guide](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/v2r1/topic/com.ibm.zos.v2r1.ikjc300/toc.htm) (both V2.1 links).

---

Comment: And both of these cases work because, in Rexx, a compound symbol consists of a prefix and a suffix, not indexes or multiple levels.  It's a simple variable-expansion-and-concatenation operation.

Answer (score 2):

Other pure (non-Object) Rexx alternatives:

```
interpret "say test." || test.0
```

or

```
say value("test." || test.0)
```

Comment: Caveat programmator with "interpret". :)

Comment: @zarchasmpgmr Oh, yeah.  Absolutely.  It's a code-injection-attack just waiting to happen.  But it's also a valid technique.

Comment: Always decoded it in 2 statements: n = test.0; say test.n; And seeing the answers, how about interpreting let's say test.test.i.test.j? (a pointer-matrix perhaps)

Answer (score 0):

The default Rexx interpreter on z/OS is Classic Rexx, not OORexx.  OORexx [has not been ported](http://www.oorexx.org/products.html) to z/OS.

Comment: So what's the quickest way to perform test.[test.0] then ?

Comment: You've nailed it. It is unfortunate that mainframe Rexx has not been extended like its non-MF counterparts. Of course, the problem would be which fork to follow: OORexx, NetRexx, Regina…they both have their pros and cons. Ob: the REXX Compiler has not been updated since 1999.

Comment: Some of us think it is unfortunate that OORexx broke with the Rexx historical path.  NetRexx was a little easier to accept, as Mike created it for a specific purpose (close integration with Java).

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind that (in z/OS, at least) the '.0' variable is not automatically updated. E.g.:

```
list.1 = 17
list.2 = 12
say 'List.0 is' list.0
```

Will give 'LIST.0', which is the default value (the variable's name) for an initialised variable.

Comment: No version of Rexx sets `list.0` like that.  Some commands (_e.g._, `EXECIO`) do, but it's not a feature of the language.

Comment: REXX on z/OS definitely works like that. I know because I've just run that code and got that result.

That's why I wrote a 'count' function that returns both the number of variables in a compound variable:
                                    
    say 'There are ' count(list.) ' elements in ''list.'''     
                                                              
gives:
                     
    There are         2  elements in 'list.' 

As you point out, EXECIO will populate the .0 version with the record count.

Comment: No Robin, it's simply an assembler function package. It also works for non-numeric suffixes. I also added 'CONTAINS' (returns TRUE if a compound variable contains a value, 'DROP' (Delete the variable with specified value) & 'FOREACH' (Iterate over all members(>) of a compound variable).

Comment: LOL - I meant the `list.0` thing, but, touche' :-)

Comment: Ah -ok. It's just that I've met people who think that 'list.0' ALWAYS contain the number of elements in the list. I've been trying to make compound variables in z/OS REXX (not ooRexx) more like modern arrays.